# Android SearchView.onQueryTextSubmit(String query)

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

I am having issues getting my submit button for the query to work. I have this part of my code here

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true); //iconify the widget
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
```

and I also have a listener

```
new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
  @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //Output the new list with the query results

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence start = "Start";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, start, duration);
            toast.show();
            return false;
        }
    };
```

When the submit button is clicked, it does not show the toast so I am assuming that when the submit button is clicked, it is not doing what it is supposed to do. I don't know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 6):

You have to call

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener());
```

on your SearchView.

Comment: what is the difference if i return true and if i return false in public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s)

Comment: For onQueryTextChange  - false if the SearchView should perform the default action of showing any suggestions if available, true if the action was handled by the listener.
For onQueryTextSubmit - true if the query has been handled by the listener, false to let the SearchView perform the default action.

Answer (score 6):

For other ppls if they need or lookin help

```
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){

           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
               Toast.makeText(context,"Our word : "+s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               return false;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
               return false;
           }
       });
       return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You are returning `false` in the end when according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html#onQueryTextSubmit(java.lang.String)) you should return `true`:

> The listener can override the standard behavior by returning true to
>   indicate that it has handled the submit request. Otherwise return
>   false to let the SearchView handle the submission by launching any
>   associated intent.